# Add custom input type to graphql-tag mutation

Tags: json, object, apollo, apollo-client, mutation

My django mutation is passing data variable as graphene.JSONString() so my $data variable needs to be or JSON or Object type. Is here any way to achieve that??

I was trying to use scalar JSON but i'me getting an error

**I'm getting an error when I'm using: $data: JSON!**

```
export const UPLOAD_SPECIFICATION = gql`
scalar JSON
mutation ($account_id: String!, $name: String, $description: String, $data: JSON!){
    uploadSpecification(account_id: $account_id, name:$name, description: $description, data: $data) {
        specification {
            id,
            name
        }
    }
}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export const UPLOAD_SPECIFICATION = gql`
mutation ($account_id: String!, $name: String, $description: String, $data: JSONObject){
    uploadSpecification(account_id: $account_id, name:$name, description: $description, data: $data) {
        specification {
            id,
            name
        }
    }
}`;
```

I need in my schema.graphql the scalar:

```
scalar JSON
scalar JSONObject

type Mutation{
uploadSpecification(..., data: JSONObject):Specification

}
```